# How to obtain the file in controller

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-2.1.3, file-upload

I want to obtain the file path inside my controller for the file uploaded in store configuration.In `system.xml` I have added the file upload section as

```
<section id="mageplaza_helloworld_section" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="301" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
    <label>Sales</label>
    <tab>sales</tab>
    <resource>Magento_Sales::config_sales</resource>
    <group id="custom_group" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="6" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" >
        <label>Security</label>
        <field id="custom_file_upload" translate="label" type="Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\File" sortOrder="6" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" >
            <label>Upload custom file</label>
            <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\File</backend_model>
            <upload_dir config="system" scope_info="1">test</upload_dir>
        </field>
    </group>
</section>
```

It's uploaded in my Magento root folder in path `"magento_root/test/default"`.

Now let's say we upload the file abc.csv, I want this file path dynamically inside my controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your system configuration value like this-

```
$this->scopeConfig->getValue('your_section/your_group/your_field', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
```